# Find character in csv, split cells in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, gsub

I have a .csv file with gene names such as `"AT1G45150"`. However, some entries have two gene names connected by an underscore, so they look like this `"AT3G01311_ATCG00940"` as seen in line 135. Is there a simple command, perhaps with something like `gsub` that not only finds and eliminates everything in the cell from the underscore on, but also sticks the second gene name in a cell immediately below the one it was found in, in the same column but the next row down? Also want to keep everything that was already in that column, just extend column length to add new members.

```
"133","AT1G45150","AT1G12200","AT2G25370","AT1G19715","AT2G46830","AT1G20870","AT4G12400","AT1G19660"
"134","AT1G47280","AT1G12410","AT2G26920","AT1G19750","AT2G46850","AT1G21400","AT4G15430","AT1G19690"
"135","AT1G47317","AT1G12530","AT2G27270","AT1G20540","AT3G01311_ATCG00940","AT1G21450","AT5G01970","AT1G19750"
"136","AT1G47420","AT1G12550","AT2G28590","AT1G20570","AT3G03470","AT1G21730","AT1G20800","AT1G19780"
"137","AT1G47500","AT1G12740","AT2G28970","AT1G20580","AT3G03980","AT1G21760","AT3G54740","AT1G19790"
"138","AT1G47570","AT1G12750","AT2G29740","AT1G20610","AT3G05040","AT1G22000","AT4G12400","AT1G19970"
```

so that it becomes

```
"133","AT1G45150","AT1G12200","AT2G25370","AT1G19715","AT2G46830","AT1G20870","AT4G12400","AT1G19660"
"134","AT1G47280","AT1G12410","AT2G26920","AT1G19750","AT2G46850","AT1G21400","AT4G15430","AT1G19690"
"135","AT1G47317","AT1G12530","AT2G27270","AT1G20540","AT3G01311","AT1G21450","AT5G01970","AT1G19750"
"136","AT1G47420","AT1G12550","AT2G28590","AT1G20570","ATCG000940","AT1G21730","AT1G20800","AT1G19780"
"137","AT1G47500","AT1G12740","AT2G28970","AT1G20580","AT3G03470","AT1G21760","AT3G54740","AT1G19790"
"138","AT1G47570","AT1G12750","AT2G29740","AT1G20610","AT3G03980","AT1G22000","AT4G12400","AT1G19970"
```

Thanks for your help!

edit: trying to provide a reproducible example, hope this is helpful:

```
> dput(droplevels(genes[133:138,]))
structure(list(g99 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G45150", "AT1G47280", 
"AT1G47317", "AT1G47420", "AT1G47500", "AT1G47570"), class = "factor"), 
g95 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G12200", "AT1G12410", 
"AT1G12530", "AT1G12550", "AT1G12740", "AT1G12750"), class = "factor"), 
y99 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT2G25370", "AT2G26920", 
"AT2G27270", "AT2G28590", "AT2G28970", "AT2G29740"), class = "factor"), 
y95 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G19715", "AT1G19750", 
"AT1G20540", "AT1G20570", "AT1G20580", "AT1G20610"), class = "factor"), 
a99 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT2G46830", "AT2G46850", 
"AT3G01311_ATCG00940", "AT3G03470", "AT3G03980", "AT3G05040"
), class = "factor"), a95 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G20870", 
"AT1G21400", "AT1G21450", "AT1G21730", "AT1G21760", "AT1G22000"
), class = "factor"), e99 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("AT1G20800", "AT3G54740", "AT4G12400", "AT4G15430", 
"AT5G01970"), class = "factor"), e95 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G19660", 
"AT1G19690", "AT1G19750", "AT1G19780", "AT1G19790", "AT1G19970"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("g99", "g95", "y99", "y95", 
"a99", "a95", "e99", "e95"), row.names = 133:138, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Where do the extra values in line 138 come from?  I you want this data in an r dataframe can you provide it in a usable input format

Comment: Could you `dput` this sample data, so we can read it in? Also, it is not clear what you want in the desired output. When the second part is moved to the row below, what happens with the elements beneath it? are they all moved down by 1 as above? If so, is the final element dropped?

Comment: gtwebb, the extra values in line 138 were a mistake. Also, I want the elements beneath to be moved down by one as well, I do not want the final elements dropped. Columns are all different in length

Comment: So if `"AT3G05040"` in column 6 is not dropped when you push down the elements, would it go to index 139?  Would you want an index 139 with all NAs except for that 6th column?

Comment: @TylerByers I do want the gene `"AT3G05040"` to be moved to index 139. As my data.frame is now, each column was originally of different lengths, but when I put them all in a df together they just cycle back to the first column member, and the whole df has as many rows as the longest column (maybe a stupid way to have done this?) If I knew how to do this to a single vector, that would be helpful too, just thought it'd be easier to apply to the whole df. Thanks for your help

Comment: So @RachelFordyce, does order of the genes matter?  Seems like it doesn't if you're reading the csv to a data frame and then moving column values "down" when there is the `_`.  If order doesn't matter, then coerce your data frame to a list by removing the index (`dplyr` way is `df <- df %>% select(-index)`, replacing `index` by `V1` or whatever that column name is, then doing an `unname(unlist(df))`.  Then use @MhairiMcNeill's answer.  If order DOES matter, then reading to a data frame and pushing down columns doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TylerByers thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that these genes are part of a bigger data frame with more information about each gene. I'd use `tidyr` and `dplyr`. Something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- 
  df %>% 
  separate(gene, c('first', 'second'), '_') %>% # Make two columns 
  gather(position, gene, first, second) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(gene))
```

I used `separate` to split the column into two, with the first column containing the first gene and the second column with the second (if it exists). Then I used `gather` to stack all the genes on top of each other and `filter` to remove rows from the missing second gene.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : 
  argument is of length zero

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've seen your data I've got a new answer. I'm a little confused about what exactly you want in the dataframe, but here's how to do it for a single vector.

```
library(stringr)

> df$a99
[1] "AT2G46830"           "AT2G46850"           "AT3G01311_ATCG00940"
[4] "AT3G03470"           "AT3G03980"           "AT3G05040"          

> unlist(str_split(df$a99, '_'))
[1] "AT2G46830" "AT2G46850" "AT3G01311" "ATCG00940" "AT3G03470" "AT3G03980"
[7] "AT3G05040"
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you maybe want to keep the data frame structure.

First load the following three packages:
`library(stringr); library(purrr); library(dplyr)`

Then your data frame looks like:

```
> genes
   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5                  V6        V7        V8        V9
1 133 AT1G45150 AT1G12200 AT2G25370 AT1G19715           AT2G46830 AT1G20870 AT4G12400 AT1G19660
2 134 AT1G47280 AT1G12410 AT2G26920 AT1G19750           AT2G46850 AT1G21400 AT4G15430 AT1G19690
3 135 AT1G47317 AT1G12530 AT2G27270 AT1G20540 AT3G01311_ATCG00940 AT1G21450 AT5G01970 AT1G19750
4 136 AT1G47420 AT1G12550 AT2G28590 AT1G20570           AT3G03470 AT1G21730 AT1G20800 AT1G19780
5 137 AT1G47500 AT1G12740 AT2G28970 AT1G20580           AT3G03980 AT1G21760 AT3G54740 AT1G19790
6 138 AT1G47570 AT1G12750 AT2G29740 AT1G20610           AT3G05040 AT1G22000 AT4G12400 AT1G19970
```

If I was just to attack the `V6` variable, I would use the following commands from `stringr`:

```
> str_sub(genes$V6, start = 1L, 
          end = ifelse(is.na(str_locate(genes$V6, '_')[,1]), -1,    
          str_locate(genes$V6, '_')[, 1] - 1))
[1] "AT2G46830" "AT2G46850" "AT3G01311" "AT3G03470" "AT3G03980" "AT3G05040"
```

But we want to generalize this to all the variables, in case you want to keep your data frame structure.  So use the `map` function from `purrr` to go through all the columns in the data frame (you also might be able use `lapply` in a similar manner, but sometimes it's hard to coerce to a dataframe).

```
> genes2 <- map(genes, function(x) { str_sub(x, start = 1L, 
               end = ifelse(is.na(str_locate(x, '_'))[,1], -1, 
               str_locate(x, '_')[,1] - 1)) }) 
            %>% as_data_frame()
```

And your data frame then looks like this:

```
> genes2
Source: local data frame [6 x 9]

     V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9
  (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)
1   133 AT1G45150 AT1G12200 AT2G25370 AT1G19715 AT2G46830 AT1G20870 AT4G12400 AT1G19660
2   134 AT1G47280 AT1G12410 AT2G26920 AT1G19750 AT2G46850 AT1G21400 AT4G15430 AT1G19690
3   135 AT1G47317 AT1G12530 AT2G27270 AT1G20540 AT3G01311 AT1G21450 AT5G01970 AT1G19750
4   136 AT1G47420 AT1G12550 AT2G28590 AT1G20570 AT3G03470 AT1G21730 AT1G20800 AT1G19780
5   137 AT1G47500 AT1G12740 AT2G28970 AT1G20580 AT3G03980 AT1G21760 AT3G54740 AT1G19790
6   138 AT1G47570 AT1G12750 AT2G29740 AT1G20610 AT3G05040 AT1G22000 AT4G12400 AT1G19970
```

Comment: I think this removed the characters after the `_` but fails to add them to the column

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't clear about adding the second part to the column.  I'll try to revisit this again tomorrow.